# How to pack each two elements in a list to tuple in scala?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, tuples, scala-collections

Input:

```
val input = List(1, 3, 6, 7, 12)
```

The output would be:

```
val output = List((1, 3), (3, 6), (6, 7), (7, 12))
```

Comment: @jwvh Many thanks for the hint, I tried "input.sliding(2).toList", kind of solve my problem, though it's not getting a list of tuples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about `input.zip(input.tail)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use s `sliding`:

```
output.sliding(2, 1).map(l => (l(0), l(1))).toList
```

or:

```
output.sliding(2, 1).map { case List(a, b) => (a, b) }.toList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
input.sliding(2).toList.map(l => (l.head, l.tail.head))
```